# Problem with saving metadata in mp3 files using eyed3 (python)

Tags: python, mp3, eyed3

I have a bunch of mp3 files in which I need to register meta tags. I use the eyed3 library. The meta tags are installed successfully (they are displayed in windows Explorer), but when you run another script that does other operations with meta tags they go empty. also now after restarting pc meta tags empty even in windows explorer. how do i save tags correctly?

tried to save like just `file.tag.save()` and `file.tag.save(version=(1,None,None))` but this didn't work

```
file = eyed3.load(path)
file.initTag()
file.album = 'blablabla'
file.lyrics.set(lyrics)
file.tag.save(version=(1,None,None))
file.tag.save()
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.